# How to find an equation that warps a grid system or transforms a number line.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, jacobian

I am a Microbiologist with no Math background.

I am looking for an equation or how to find equations that warp a normal XY plane in the Jacobian fashion. Like this https://youtu.be/CfW845LNObM?t=61 I want to end up with an f(x,y) that returns f(x',y'). In other words, I want an f(x,y) that will allow me to see how a point (x,y) moves to (x',y'). I want, in my hand, a function that when I plug in (x,y) it spits out x',y'.

Idea/Method.

A Jacobian matrix tracks or should track the movements of all points. If I can get the partial derivatives, then I can integrate to obtain the initial function.

In 1D, I'd like to think of a y=f(x) that returns a curve. So when I have the curve, I'd like to find f(x). I like to think of this https://youtu.be/CfW845LNObM?t=143 as a graph. If it can be seen as a graph then I'd like to obtain the function that graphs it. But I could be wrong.

I've heard of complex analysis but I'm yet to wet my feet in it.

Comment: Check the book tristan Needham Visual complex analysis, chapter 2 may be what you are looking for

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my interest is in the real plane, not the complex plane. Any assistance? Much gratitude. I've updated my post.

Comment: Yes, the method used in complex functions there can be extra polated to vector functions

Comment: It's hard to know in any concrete sense what you need to "warp a 2D grid".  Explaining the intended application would make it more likely a response can be useful to you.  If the goal were merely to have a  2D grid, there are many approaches (e.g. triangulation), so the purpose of getting the grid by "warping" a uniform grid needs to be shared.

Comment: You mean like these examples? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Growth_and_Form#17._On_the_Theory_of_Transformations,_or_the_Comparison_of_Related_Forms ?

Comment: @kimchilover Well, it really is the same thing isn't it.

Comment: @NyaLegoo I think we all are struggling to understand what you are asking, precisely.  Part of the problem with your current question statement is that it mixes up end goals with methods and techniques.  Can you give a simple concrete instance of what you want to do?

Comment: @kimchilover I'm sorry I'm not clear. The methods or techniques was just my hunch. The end goal is I want in my hand a function that converts a normal Cartesian grid to whatever stretched result I already have. Like, I have 2 planes. One is before transformation the other is after. I want the function that produces that effect. I hope I'm a little bit clearer.

Comment: What does "whatever stretched result I already have" mean?  You want a method that given two shapes in the plane, produces a function that maps the one shape to the other?  As in, a fun-house mirror, which makes  the reflection of my face look like the outline of Portugal?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes.

Comment: @kimchilover, what do you think of what's going on here https://youtu.be/CfW845LNObM?t=65

Comment: I'll reply in the next few hours.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you.

Comment: I saw the vido you mentioned, and am no wiser than I was before about what your question might actually be.  I also took a look at the book that Buraian mentioned in his comment, and think you should look at it.

Comment: @kimchilover, I have the book. I'm taking a look at it. I feel that it explains how a few functions work. I feel It's a little deep waters for me at the moment. But I'm trying. Regarding how my question is structured, we agreed with your analogy. Your face -> outline of Portugal. I think this is the perfect analogy of what I'm asking. https://youtu.be/CfW845LNObM?t=65 You can see the normal straight grid and a warped one.

Comment: @kimchilover, I really think we are talking about the same thing here. The link I've provided only shows a nice grid. But I think the idea is the same.

Comment: @Buraian, @kimchilover; Does this image representation  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant shed any more light? What I'm saying is I need to obtain the f.

Comment: It maybe noted 3blue1brown's animation is a parameterized animation like the transformations change as you crank some kind of parameter value

Comment: @Buraian, be that as it may, do you understand what I'm after?

Comment: Yes, I thought you would have inferred that from the answer I wrote. It's mostly differential geometry concepts you are after I think, there is a popular example of a torus turning into a coffe mug in it. Some kind of deformations of structures like that , isn't it?

Comment: @Buraian, Yes. As long as this process lets me obtain the function that does the magic, I'll be the happiest being.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm it seems you still aren't convinced of my suggest, I'll use this answer as a 'sales pitch' of the book (*).

Page-71, how the function $e^z$ wraps the cartesian grid:

[image]

And here is how the book explains the complex derivative pg-196:

[image]

As simple as it looks, at a certain point on our input plane, imagine an infinitesimal vector emanating from that point. Now, the complex derivative acts on this vector and does an amplitwist, which is an amplification and a rotation.

---

Here is a worked out example on how a complex mapping works, I'll give you a sheet of paper and what you do is put flags at each point on the paper. Maybe use a ruler to mark the points on the graph (like a number line) , to determine a point on the plane we will need two numbers on this flag (why?).

Now, we can think of a complex function as taking in the location of the flag on the first grid (z-plane) and where you should put the flag on the output grid (w-plane). Let's take for example the complex function $f(z)=z^2$, we can expand this function in cartesian form as:

$$ f(z) = (x+iy)^2 = x^2 -y^2 + 2xiy$$

Setting $f(z)=u+iv$, our $u=x^2 - y^2 $ and $v=2xy$, think of $u$ as the horizontal in the new plane and $v$ as the vertical (in place of $x$ and $y$). Recall that $x^2 - y^2=c$ denotes the equation of hyperbola, this means that in our mapping hyperbolas gets mapped to straight lines as shown in page-191 of the book:

[image]

Left: z-plane, right: w- plane

There is a lot more in this book than I can show here. I took a long time to work through the first few chapters but when you start understanding the topics , I can tell you it's a real joy.

---

If you can wait for a few more months, then Tristan Needham (same  prof who wrote his book) is writing a differential geometry book and it should probably contain all about the kind of mappings you are looking for.

*: I hope other MSE folk will be ok with this kind of posts

Comment: let me study this. You have no idea how much I'm yearning to understand all this and satisfy my inquiry. You have no idea how much pleasure I would derive from this.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about all this. You have given as an example e^z as the function that warps the grid. My question has always been given z-plane and w-plane, how can I find e^z. From what I can surmise, the book is showing how everything is happening. It has z-plane, w-plane and the function. In my case I don't have the function and it's what I want.

Comment: Oh, for that if the complex function is analytic, you have to solve can derive a differential equation teh function must have following the cauchy rienmann equation then derive the form of function

Comment: See from page-220

Comment: thanks. Let me take a look at it. Hope it's what I've been searching.

Comment: Hypothetically, with this method I can do the following: If I have z and w-planes, I should be able to distort points on w-plane and the mapping function should adjust accordingly.